# Efficient visualisation of arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, visualization

First, I don't know the word for the set. I have n cases and the set I have is 2^n which lists all their "arrangements" present or absent, so a summation of combinations with k from 0 to n.

Each arrangement has a value and I need to plot this arrangement (in JS with plotly or D3, so anything is doable) but I unsure what graph to use.
It's actually an biological problem regarding epistasis, where mutations together are not additive, but may synergise.

**My thoughts**
The dataset is a square, but that is not visually helpful: the bottom half minus the diagonal of that would be straightforward n-choose-2 combinations (e.g. --++,-+-+), the diagonal n-choose-1 states (---+), while the rest would be higher combinations (-+++), plus the null state (----).
In my code I easily make the display version of the set by iterating through 2^n and converting each index to a binary in string format
`(i).toString(2).padStart(mutation_number,'0').split("").map((v,i)=>v == "1" ? "+" : "-")`. However, a list, e.g. bar chart, seems a terrible way to represent the dataset.
The best I could think is a diamond of lines of circles where each tier `i` is a the `n-choose-i` subset. But it would require arrows and may be confusing...

Comment: Do you mean the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)? If so, I don't think there is a particularly good way to visualize all the elements of a power set as a two-dimensional diagram. A natural geometrical representation is as the vertices of an $n$-dimensional hypercube, but that is hard to draw and harder to interpret.

Comment: Yes! Thanks, that is it.

Comment: A hypercube graph is basically what I was thinking. So you have answered my question.
In truth, it needn't be a static representation. Nor simply animated —watching hypercubes rotate is rather trippy, so interactive is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

User856 notes that this is called a `power set`.

> I don't think there is a particularly good way to visualize all the
> elements of a power set as a two-dimensional diagram. A natural
> geometrical representation is as the vertices of an -dimensional
> hypercube, but that is hard to draw and harder to interpret.

For my application I ended up using a graph-like representation, where node width represented the value and the user could drag the nodes to avoid confusion. This can be found in [epistasis.mutanalyst.com](https://epistasis.mutanalyst.com/) by using the first "demo" data.
[image: network]